# CSS3 compatibility with IE - Background Stretching

Tags: css

I'm having problem with stretching my logo within a desired logo size. Below is my Css3 code. it works fine with other browser except IE. Please use IE to view my problem. www.allwireinc.com please help.

```
h1.logo { 
    width: 145px; height: 120px; }

h1.logo a {
    background: url(http://www.allwireinc.com/images/weblogo.png) no-repeat left;
        -moz-background-size: auto 100%;
    -o-background-size: auto 100%
    -webkit-background-size: auto 100%;
    background-size: auto 100%;
        display: block; 
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of IE don't support that.

However, you could replace it with an `img`, and you could stretch that.

Answer (score -1):

On its own, older versions of IE don't support that feature (and many others). You might try [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) and see if it works. Otherwise you'll have to decide whether or not you are willing to live with the limitation, or if you want to write some Javascript to take care of it for you.

Comment: PIE's documentation says that background-size would be ignored in IE 6-9: http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/